# WordPress Multisite Login Access

Tags: multisite, login, htaccess

I have a multisite installation and use an .htaccess directive to close access to wp-login.php.

```
<files wp-login.php>
errordocument 403 http://example.com/restricted/
order deny,allow
deny from all
</files>
```

Is there a way that I can allow access to a specific individual site using another directive?

I don't know how multisite generates those URLs, as I don't see an obvious rewrite rule.

Comment: So you want to restrict access to `./wp-login.php` for all sites except for one in particular, correct? Are you using a **subdirecory** or a **subdomain** installation? Is the site that is to be permitted access the main site, or a sub-site?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide restricted access, you should add an additional string with the `/wp-login.php` URL. For example:

```
http://example.com/wp-login.php?restricted_site_access=key_string
```

If the URL does not have such a string parameter, then you can redirect them to a 404 page; you don't need to rewrite the `.htaccess` file for it.